# How to draw a polygon on a Bing Map?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I am using the BingMapsTask  and BingMapsDirectionsTask  I would like to draw a polygon through a series of LON/LAT coordinates, so that an area of the map will be marked (please see attached picture. Can it be done, and if so how?

EitanB

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the Bing Maps SDK documentation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846499.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With Updated version : This will be the best option, samples with link to GitHub code
http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/